# Constructor test fails on toString() function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, constructor, tostring

These are the constructors in my header file:

```
CTree(char ch); 

CTree(char ch, CTree *kidsVal, CTree *sibsVal, CTree *prevVal);
```

These are my implementations:

```
//constructor
CTree::CTree(char toAdd, CTree *kidsVal, CTree *sibsVal, CTree *prevVal) { 
    data = toAdd; 
    kids = kidsVal; 
    sibs = sibsVal; 
    prev = prevVal; 
}

//constructor
CTree::CTree(char ch) {
    data = ch;
    kids = NULL;
    sibs = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
}
```

This is my toString() in my header file:

```
std::string toString();
```

This is my toString() implementation:

```
//toString
std::string CTree::toString() { 
    std::string str;
    std::ostringstream oss; 

    oss << "\n"; 
    oss << data; 

    if (kids != NULL) { 
        oss << kids->toString(); 
    } 

    if (sibs != NULL) { 
        oss << sibs->toString(); 
    } 

    return oss.str();
}
```

And this is where CTreeTest fails, on the very first test:

```
static void constructorTest() {

        // build a few trees with constructor

        CTree t1('A');

        assert(t1.toString() == "A\n");

        CTree t2('b');

        assert(t2.toString() == "b\n");

        CTree t3('^');

        assert(t3.toString() == "^\n");

    }
```

Cannot figure out why.

Comment: What does your `toString()` print in each of the three cases?

Comment: "A" instead of "A\n", "b" instead of "b\n" and so on..

Comment: Try writing `oss << "\n" ` just before the `return oss.str()` statement

Comment: Tried that. Still the same result.

Comment: Do your assertions fail?

Comment: BTW when you print out a `std::string str = "A\n";` It will just show the character `A`, as `\n' is a newline character, however I think the assertion shouldn't fail

Comment: It looks like your code is going to be printing out "\nA" etc., instead of "A\n"... right?

Comment: @Lilhieste I switched the positions of oss << "\n" and oss << data and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Making the change suggested by @Lilshieste allows your code to work.  There's a simple, runnable version on ideone:  https://ideone.com/jcBZGv If you are still having problems, then you need to supply more information to identify what is unique about your system.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** The following program (which in my opinion is similar to yours) has no problems passing the assertion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>

class CTree {
  public: 
      CTree(char c) : data(c) {}

      std::string toString() {
          std::ostringstream oss;
          oss << data;
          oss << '\n';

          return oss.str();
      }

  private:
      char data;
};

int main() {
    CTree t1('A');
    assert(t1.toString() == "A\n"); //passes assertion
    std::cout << t1.toString();

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I swapped out my function with yours and still get the same result.